# Nginx works on http but not on https, showing welcome to centos page

Tags: nginx

I am trying to server flask application with ssl enabled.

myproject.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target
[Service]
User=userone
Group=userone
WorkingDirectory=/home/userone/userone-application
Environment="PATH=/home/userone/userone-application/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/userone/userone-application/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/userone/myproject.sock -m 007 app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx.conf:

```
server{

listen 80;

server_name <domain>.com;

       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;



 location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/home/userone/myproject.sock;
    }}
    server {
    listen       443 ssl;
        listen       [::]:443;
        server_name  <domain>.com;
       root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.key;
```

However I keep getting the landing page for centos

[image]

When I did not use ssl, i.e `listen 80;` instead, it is serving the correct page.

Comment: Did your conf file get cut off?   I don't see the closing brace (`}`) for the last `server {` section with the `listen 443` in it .  Does it hava a `location /` section in it as well?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I forgot to close it when I pasted the code here. There are no syntax errors. The weird thing is if I change listen 443 to just listen 80, it works properly.

Comment: The location / section is as in the code above

Comment: The code above contains a location section for `listen 80` but none for `listen 443` .  Can you [edit] your question to include the entire configuration?